# Is it possible to reset/reinitialize a pipeline (or BackgroundWorker) in OmniThreadLibrary?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2010, omnithreadlibrary

By re-initialize, I mean **stop the running tasks** (or even **kill the threads** if I have to) & revert back as if the pipeline/threads were never initialized / started.

My code (I'm using **delphi 2010, OmniThreadLibrary 3.02**) looks like this:

```
procedure SomeProc();
var
   AFile : TOmniValue;
begin
     APipeline := Parallel.Pipeline.NumTasks(5).Stage(StageProc).Run;

     AFile.CreateNamed(['FileID', FileID, 'FileName', FileName]);
     MyPipeline.Input.Add(AFile);
end;
// --------------- //
procedure StageProc(const Input, Output : IOmniBlockingCollection; const Task : IOmniTask);
begin
    // ...
end;
```

**I need something like this:**

```
// --------------- //
procedure ResetPipeline();
begin
     // Stop any task running inside StageProc() & reset pipeline, ie.
     KillTasks(pipeline);
     pipeline := nil;
end;
```

### Notes

1. **FWIW, yes, I'm fully aware that this is really a bad idea!**
2. I'm also well aware that the best approach would be to send *a stop signal* to tasks and wait for them to nicely shutdown, and check often for stop signals inside tasks. **I'm not interested in that for this very particular case.**
3. Although the code above only mention pipelines, a solution to reset BackgroundWorker would be enough for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Send a stop signal. Like nature intended. I'd expect that OTL won't offer up routines for perform the sort of abuse that you are proposing.

Comment: Thanks David, but as I *already* stated that I'm not interested in that in this particular case. I'm more interested in killing (or re-initializing the pipeline) rather than nicely stopping the tasks! (yes **even** given the downfalls of such approach)

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer**: Forceful termination of threads is not advisable – please don't try this at home.*

I believe you can do what you want like this:

```
GlobalParallelPool.WaitOnTerminate_sec := 0;
GlobalParallelPool.CancelAll;
```

Comment: Thanks David but I'm afraid that **didn't terminate neither tasks nor threads**. Again, I **really** understand how bad it is to terminate threads but in my *particular case*, it's both safe and the way to go..

Comment: According to my reading of the code, this should result in a bunch of calls to TerminateThread. You have the code too, and a working test bed. Perhaps you could inspect in the debugger and work out why those TerminateThread calls don't run.

Comment: I did; it lead me to nowhere (plus I'm not comfortable changing OTL, I don't want to break something). Primoz (OTL author) [aknowledged here](http://otl.17slon.com/forum/index.php/topic,426.msg1488.html#msg1488) that there are indeed valid reasons to kill a **task** (although I'm pretty sure it *will* be abused)

Comment: FWIW, I finally resolved in my particular case to literally **kill the EXE** (it's an invisible EXE running in the background), it's really a shame that I have to resolve to such brutal techniques, but until OTL allows this, it seems there's no way to reset/kill tasks in OTL.